# How to add js function to jquery calender and dynamic tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I tried to make some dates highlighted with jquery calender and I did it successfully just for border but I can't for background. But I still don't able to add dynamic tooltip. And I need also to call function on click.

How can I do so (function on click - highlight background - dynamic tooltip "inclined into dates array") ?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        var disabledDays = ["2017-5-21", "2017-5-24", "2017-5-27", "2017-5-28"]; 
        var tooltip = ["1 tip", "2 tip", "3 tip"];
        var date = new Date();
        jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
            $('#datepicker').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                    var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();
                    for (i = 0; i < disabledDays.length; i++) {
                        if($.inArray(y + '-' + (m+1) + '-' + d,disabledDays) != -1) {
                            return [1, 'calender_highlight', 'tooltip']; 
                        }
                    }
                    return [true];
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

```css
.calender_highlight{
           border:2px solid #ffd800;
           background-color:#ffd800;
       }
       .calender_highlight:hover{
         border:2px solid green;
       }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the html for the datepicker is generated dynamically you will have to use the correct event binding, what you are looking for is the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) functionality of jquery:

```
$('#datepicker').on('mouseenter','.ui-state-default',  function(e) {
  $(this).attr('title', 'My tooltip');
});
```

In that way you will get the browser's default title-style. There is also a [bootstrap tooltip](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips) function you could consider.